# If I am working In Vanilla React Native, Can I use Frameworks Developed in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

This is a very basic question I'm sure, but i am working in React Native and have no plans on downloading, installing, or using Expo. There is a styling Framework, [Nuton](https://codecanyon.net/item/nuton-online-learning-react-native-template/38175136), that was built using Expo, My question, is will I be able to use this Framework without having to start an expo project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find the specific library Nuton you are referring to, please edit your post and add a link to it for a more detailed answer.

However, to give you a basic understanding:

If you have to use "expo install Nuton" in the command line to add this library to your project, then yes, expo is required in order to use this library.

If you can use "npm install Nuton" then no, expo is not required. However, Nuton's package may have expo components it will install within the library itself. Whether you want to use expo or not should not matter in this case.